# How do I load a .p12 certificate on a shared host environment?

Tags: asp.net, certificate

So I'm connecting to a third party api which requires to load a .p12 certificate in order to authenticate. All works fine on localhost, but on remote shared host I get the dreaded "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" error. My site is asp.net framework 4.7 and and has a secure ssl connection. I already added

```
'System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

to Global.asax (if not it will not even run on localhost). Appreciate any lights on how to solve this.

Here's the test code that works fine on localhost:

```
 System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
    Dim certPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/BolsasPixCert.p12")

    Dim uidCert As X509Certificate2 = New X509Certificate2(certPath, "")
    Dim options = New RestClientOptions("https://pix.api.efipay.com.br") With {
            .ClientCertificates = New X509CertificateCollection() From {
        uidCert
    },
    .ThrowOnAnyError = True
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally found the answer on the smarterasp.net KB:

1. add X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet:

   Dim uidCert As X509Certificate2 = New X509Certificate2(certPath, "",X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet)
2. Make sure you're referencing System.Net.Http.dll in bin folder